# Padding sequences in tensorflow with tf.pad

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to load imdb dataset in python. I want to pad the sequences so that each sequence is of same length. I am currently doing it with numpy. What is a good way to do it in tensorflow with tf.pad. I saw the given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pad) but I dont know how to apply it with a 2 d matrix. 
Here is my current code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import imdb
max_features = 5000
print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)

def padSequence(dataset,max_length):
    dataset_p = []
    for x in dataset:
        if(len(x) <=max_length):
            dataset_p.append(np.pad(x,pad_width=(0,max_length-len(x)),mode='constant',constant_values=0))
        else:
            dataset_p.append(x[0:max_length])
    return np.array(x_train_p)

max_length = max(len(x) for x in x_train)
x_train_p = padSequence(x_train,max_length)
x_test_p = padSequence(x_test,max_length)
print("input x shape: " ,x_train_p.shape)
```

Can someone please help ? 
I am using tensorflow 1.0
In Response to the comment:
The padding dimensions are given by
`# 'paddings' is [[1, 1,], [2, 2]]`.

I have a 2 d matrix where every row is of different length. I want to be able to pad to to make them of equal length. In my padSequence(dataset,max_length) function, I get the length of every row with len(x) function. Should I just do the same with tf ? Or is there a way to do it like Keras Function

```
x_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on why it is not straightforward to apply tf.pad to your specific problem? The given examples in your link is already for 2d matrices.

Comment: Well, the padding dimensions are given by  # 'paddings' is [[1, 1,], [2, 2]]. I have a 2 d matrix where every row is of different length. I want to be able to pad to to make them of equal length. In my padSequence(dataset,max_length) function, I get the length of every row with len(x) function. Should I just do the same with tf ? Or is there a way to do it like Keras Function x_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)

Comment: There is pad_sequences function from keras in tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences .
Other than that, I couldn't find any other way than what you are doing in numpy.

Comment: How can you make the second dimension of different length? Could you please teach me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use tf.pad, according to me you have to iterate for each row.

Code will be something like this:

```
max_length = 250
number_of_samples = 5

padded_data = np.ndarray(shape=[number_of_samples, max_length],dtype=np.int32)   
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

for i in range(number_of_samples):
    reviewToBePadded = dataSet[i] #dataSet numpy array
    paddings = [[0,0], [0, maxLength-len(reviewToBePadded)]]
    data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(reviewToBePadded,tf.int32)
    data_tf = tf.reshape(data_tf,[1,len(reviewToBePadded)])
    data_tf =  tf.pad(data_tf, paddings, 'CONSTANT')
    padded_data[i] = data_tf.eval()
print(padded_data)
sess.close()
```

New to Python, possibly not the best code. But I just want to explain the concept.